# What is the twin-stick shooter being played in the beginning of this video?

Tags: game-identification

What is the game being played at the beginning of this video

It appears to be a science-fiction aircraft twin stick shooter, and the controller suggests he's playing it on an Xbox One. He doesn't discuss the game itself, and it doesn't come up in the video after the initial few seconds.

There's one person in the YouTube comments also asking what game it is, but he doesn't get an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe he is playing 'X-Morph Defense' at the beginning of the video.

[X-Morph Defense Gameplay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qm8PKiqaS5A)

Comment: Yes, that's certainly it. Thank you!
I guess my searching failed because I didn't call it "tower defence" when I looked.